# Can mattresses relieve scoliosis pain?

Tags: physiology, sleep

I found a lot of reviews of mattresses that claim they can help with back pain from [scoliosis](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/scoliosis/symptoms-causes/syc-20350716). I was really surprised because I haven't heard about them before.

Here are some examples:

- [MedicalNewsToday: Mattress for scoliosis: 7 options](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/best-mattress-for-scoliosis)

  > People with scoliosis have an abnormal curve, which may be in the shape of an S or a C, in their spine. People with this condition may benefit from a certain type of mattress.
- [Health.com: The 10 Best Mattresses for Back Pain](https://www.health.com/condition/sleep/best-mattress-for-back-pain)

  This one doesn't mention scoliosis in particular, but back pain more generally:

  > While this pain can be caused by a number of variables, your mattress is a fundamental one—it can cause back pain or make it worse if you’re not sleeping on the right mattress.
- [Talk About Sleep: Top 10 Mattresses for Neck Pain Relief – Your Way to Healthier Sleep](https://www.talkaboutsleep.com/best-mattress-for-neck-pain/)

  Similarly, this one talks about on neck pain, rather than scoliosis in particular:

  > However, many people continually find themselves suffering from ongoing neck pain without realizing that it could just be their current mattress choice which is the real culprit!

I can't find any scientific articles on this issue.

Can a particular type of mattress help relieve pain from scoliosis?

Comment: I just shot myself in the foot by clarifying the question to focus on scoliosis, and *then* doing a bit of research and [making a shocking finding](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0140673603147927) about non-specific low-back pain - although I question what "double-blind" means here. [I have a very firm mattress and low-back pain, and will now need to think about replacing it.]